# How could I remove this FormatException problem

Tags: c#, exception

I wrote a code for converting string value to TimeSpan value.
Sometimes it has FormatException not always. It is usually works well.

To subtract string as time, I used DateTime.Parse for each string value.

```
TimeSpan timespan = DateTime.Parse(logs_temp[i + 1].time).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(logs_temp[i].time));
```

It is my part of code.

```
public class log
{
    [XmlElement("command")]
    public int command { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("param")]
    public int param { get; set;}
    [XmlElement("time")]
    public string time { get; set; }
}

 List<log> logs = logs_temp.ToList();

// logs and logs_temp have same command and param item. However add timespan bewteewn two commands in 
// time item
for (int i = 0; i <= logs_temp.Count - 1; i++)
{
    logs[i].command = logs_temp[i].command;
    logs[i].param = logs_temp[i].param;

    //Get a timespan between two sequencial command log
    if (i + 1 < logs_temp.Count)
    {   // I could find Format exception there
        TimeSpan timespan = DateTime.Parse(logs_temp[i + 1].time).Subtract(DateTime.Parse(logs_temp[i].time));

    //add second value as string but cannot
    logs[i].time = timespan.TotalSeconds.ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DateTime.Parse tries to parse it using the current PC culture. If it can't it will throw the format exception. So I guess your supplied time string is different sometimes. So set a break point to check.

Best would be to use [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netcore-3.1) or the

```
dateString = "05/01/2009 01:30:42 PM -05:00";
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt zzz", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
     Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", dateString, dateValue, dateValue.Kind);
else
     Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", dateString);
```

Comment: The best choice would be using the [DateTime.TryParseExact function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netcore-3.1)